# Update complex model in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, updatemodel

How can I update a complex model? I have the following View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Tidrapportering.Models.Week>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <table width="100%">
        <% foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: task.Customer.CustomerName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: task.TaskName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% foreach (var ts in task.TimeSegments)
                   { %>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Hours", ts.Hours)%>
                <% } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Spara tid" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

And I tried update it as usual just calling UpdataModel on the model object: UpdateModel(week); But that didn't work. So I read something about having to update each property separately in complex models, and tried to adapt it to my situation. Here's my attempt in the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTasks(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        //try
        //{
            Week week = _model.GetWeek(id);


            foreach (var task in week.Tasks)
            {
                foreach (var timeSegment in task.TimeSegments)
                {                        
                    UpdateModel(timeSegment.Hours, "Hours");
                }
            }


            //UpdateModel(week);
            _model.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}
        //catch
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
```

But that didn't work either. It seems to work if the property is a string, but this is an int, and the compiler complains that it must be a reference type to be used as a TModel.

I don't know if this is the way to go, I just need to understand how to be able to update a complex type model like this. This can't be too uncommon so there must be some standard method, but I can't figure it out...

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The following works:

Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTasks(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            Week week = _model.GetWeek(id);
            for (int i = 0; i < week.TaskList.Count; i++)
            {
                var task = week.TaskList[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < task.TimeSegmentList.Count; j++)
                {
                    int hours = Int32.Parse(collection["TaskList[" + i + "].TimeSegmentList[" + j + "].Hours"]);
                    week.TaskList[i].TimeSegmentList[j].Hours = hours;
                }
            }

            //UpdateModel(week);
            _model.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.TaskList.Count; i++)
       {
           var task = Model.TaskList[i];
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: task.Customer.CustomerName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: task.TaskName %>
        </td>
        <% for (int j = 0; j < task.TimeSegmentList.Count; j++)
           { %>
        <td>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TaskList[i].TimeSegmentList[j].Hours, new { @class = "hourInput" })%>
        </td>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

However, the updating has to be manual like this, which seems unnecessarily complex. I found a post by Phil Haack (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) which seems to suggest this should be possible to do in a simpler way, like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditTasks(Week week)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateModel(week);
            _model.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I.e. simply receiving the Week as the parameter for the method (in Haacks example it doesn't even seem he has to call UpdateModel, just having the View bound to the objects seems to be enough, so I would only have to save it in the database... But it doesn't work for me. The Week object that is returned doesn't seem to be the same one sent to the view, it has no items in its collections of tasks, e.g.

So why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `for` instead of `foreach`

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <table width="100%">
        <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++)
           { 
              var task = Model.Tasks[i];
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: task.Customer.CustomerName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: task.TaskName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% for (int j = 0; j < task.TimeSegments.Count; j++)
                   { %>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Model.Tasks["+i+"].TimeSegments["+j+"].Hours")%>
                <% } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Spara tid" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Alright, I could try that. I don't immediately see how that will make a difference (the properties show properly in the View, that is not a problem, it's just the update that doesn't work). What about the action method? How should that look to update properly? (As I mentioned, the current one is not correct, the compiler won't allow the int value timeSegment.Hours as TModel in UpdateMethod().

Comment: @Anders Svensson: Try updating the week instance: `UpdateModel(week)`

Comment: Thanks, changing to a for instead of foreach helped. I can make it work now, I am just still not able to update the model in a simple way. See my update above. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: @Anders Svensson: What happens if you do `UpdateModel(week)` ? But get the week from the model not as action parameter.

Comment: Doesn't work either, I'm afraid. I get a populated object, but it has all the old values when the page refreshes, not the changed ones. I don't understand where the unpopulated Week object comes from when I do try to receive it back as a parameter either. Why doesn't it work the same as in the Haack example? Is it because my Week object uses nested for loops to get at lower level properties?

Comment: @Anders Svensson: Don't even consider using week as action parameter, you must get it from the model because you are updating some values and not replacing the entire object. Are you sure `UpdateModel(week)` doesn't work ? Maybe it binds correctly, but the changes are not persisted. What ORM are you using ?

Comment: Maybe, but if I inspect the object after post (even if I get it directly from the model by getting it again by its id) the changes aren't there. I'm using the Entity Framework.

Comment: Anyway, it works by manually updating the model at least, so I'm marking this as answer now. Thanks for your help!